# what should come first: optional argument or argument

Tags: bash, terminal, command, command-line-interface, git-bash

I beginner in using technology like bash and command line and I have take any course about just youtube videos so while I'm using it I'm wondering what should come first.

for example:

```
read name -p "some text"
```

or should I do it like this

```
read -p "some text" name
```

and why should we one put over the another?

Comment: Follow the documentation: `help read`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convention is to put options first. See the [POSIX Utility Syntax Guidelines](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html):

> Guideline 9:
>
> All options should precede operands on the command line.

That said, GNU utilities (including bash `read`) tend to be lenient and accept them anywhere:

```
$ ls .bashrc -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me 2031 Nov 21 10:28 .bashrc
```

While BSD utilities tend to reject them after operands:

```
$ ls .bashrc -l
ls: -l: No such file or directory
.bashrc
```